# How I get the return value of a javascript addeventlistener input

Tags: javascript, return-value, addeventlistener

I try to code a bmi calculator.

I want that the snippet listen on an html input field. If someone writes a number into the input field, the written input should show instantly on the screen. But! With the input I want to calc.  If I wrote ***return res*** into the **function** I get an error:

How I can use the return value?

Have anyone a solution?

Work:

```js
document.getElementById("formInputBodySize").addEventListener("input", fBodySize);

function fBodySize() {
    let arrBodySize = [];
    arrBodySize.push(this.value);

    let res = Number(arrBodySize[arrBodySize.length - 1]);

    document.getElementById('titleWeight').innerText = res;
}
```

I try:

Not Work:

```js
document.getElementById("formInputBodySize").addEventListener("input", fBodySize);

function fBodySize() {
    let arrBodySize = [];
    arrBodySize.push(this.value);

    let res = Number(arrBodySize[arrBodySize.length - 1]);

    return res;
}

let result = fBodySize() + 10;

document.getElementById('titleWeight').innerText = result;
```

Comment: The error in your live demo is caused by you not having any HTML in it.

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading your question several times I think you mean this:

```js
document.getElementById("formInputBodySize").addEventListener("input", fBodySize);
let arrBodySize = [];
function fBodySize() {
  let size = this.value;
  size = isNaN(size) || size.trim()==""? 0: +size; // make it number
  if (size) {
    arrBodySize.push(size);
    document.getElementById('titleWeight').innerText = size+10;
  }
  else document.getElementById('titleWeight').innerText = "";
}
```

```html
Body size:<input type="text" id="formInputBodySize" /> Title weight: <span id="titleWeight"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I explained my problem wrong? I want a simple solution like this, but it does not work:

```js
document.getElementById('formInputBodySize').addEventListener('input', fBodySize);
document.getElementById('formInputWeight').addEventListener('input', fWeight);

function fBodySize() {
    return this.value;
}

function fWeight() {
    return this.value;
}

document.getElementById('formInputBmi').value = fBodySize() / (fWeight() * fWeight());
```

Sorry for my bad english. My native language is german :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="number" id="formInputBodySize"  
oninput="fBodySize(this.value)">

<script>

function fBodySize(elInput) {
let arrBodySize = [];
arrBodySize.push(elInput);

let res = Number(arrBodySize[arrBodySize.length - 1]);

document.getElementById('titleWeight').innerText = res;
}

</script>
```

Comment: oninput is just fine

Comment: i changed to oninput but from my point of view onkeyup is more handle

Comment: You also do not perform the calculation